# How to override \label to create two \newlabel's?

Tags: cross-referencing

I am attempting to override `\label` so it will automatically create two labels.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\origlabel\label
\renewcommand{\label}[1]{\origlabel{vol1:#1}\origlabel{#1}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Beginning}\label{chap:begin}
\chapter{Middle}\label{chap:middle}
\chapter{End}\label{chap:end}
\end{document}
```

When I look at the `.aux` file, there are two problems:

1. `\newlabel` command does not contain "vol1".
2. There is only one `\newlabel` per `\label` instead two.

**note**

Both answers were acceptable based on my original vague question.  Accepted answer was able to interpret the complete question (as updated now).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: If I try your redefinition and do `\label{x}`, I get `\newlabel{vol1:x}{{1}{1}}` in the `aux` file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Addition to egreg's answer:

`\label` is redefined by package `nameref` that is loaded by `hyperref` via `\AtBeginDocument`. Therefore it is enough to load `nameref` before redefining:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}

\newcommand{\origlabel}{}
\let\origlabel\label
\renewcommand*{\label}[1]{\origlabel{vol1:#1}}
```

But the redefinition can additionally be put into `\AtBeginDocument` for the case there are other packages involved.

---

Also the questions talks about **two** labels, then additional stuff has to be done. `\label` tries to be invisible regarding spaces. If space is detected before it suppresses the following spaces. This mechanism does not work for consecutive `\label`s and the new definition should be surrounded by `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack`:

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newcommand*{\orig@label}{}%
  \let\orig@label\label
  \renewcommand*{\label}[1]{%
    \@bsphack
    \orig@label{#1}%
    \orig@label{vol1:#1}%
    \@esphack
  }%
  \makeatother
}%
```

---

What is the purpose of the added `vol1:`? If the labels are used inside another document,
then packages that are able to import foreign labels (`xr`, `xr-hyper`, `zref-xr`) usually allow the addition of a prefix for the label names. Assuming the main TeX file is called `firstvolume.tex`, then the other document uses something like:

```
xr/xr-hyper: \externaldocument[vol1:]{firstvolume}
zref-xr: \zxrsetup{...}\zexternaldocument*[vol1:]{firstvolumne}
```

Comment: Purpose was to allow a very large two part publication (many authors and editors) to be built by chapter, part, or the entire book and still have the references work.  I am using xr for "standalone" building, thanks for the the other package suggestions.

Comment: I think (?) there is a typo in the code here: presumably it should be
    `\orig@label{#1}% \orig@label{vol1:#1}%`

Comment: @FreddieManners The first code block is an addition to `egreg`'s example that only uses `\orig@label{vol:#1}%`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific, my bad.  In the *second* code block you have `\renewcommand*{\label}[1]{ ... }` and inside that command body you have `\label{#1}\label{vol1:#1}` but this appears to cause `\label` to enter an infinite loop.  Changing the calls inside the body to `\orig@label` seemed to be what was intended.

Comment: @FreddieManners Yes I see, thanks, answer fixed.

Answer (score 14):

I can reproduce the problem when `hyperref` is loaded, because it redefines `\label`.

Workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\origlabel\label
  \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\origlabel{vol1:#1}}
}

\begin{document}

\section{A}\label{x}

\end{document}
```

The entry in the `.aux` file will be

```
\newlabel{vol1:x}{{1}{1}{A}{section.1}{}}
```

Comment: Sometimes I wish I am having your marble.

Comment: +1 Moral of the story: The OP should always supply a complete document that shows the problem (or rely on someone with a crystal ball:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle point well taken!